# CakePHP if else to display an ARRAY or FIRST (one row) or NULL php echo

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, if-statement, echo

I've got a table, that at any point may have NOTHING to display, ONE row or MULTIPLE rows.

In my first go I set the variable as an ARRAY finding ALL, but obviously if there's 1 row or 0 rows CakePHP throws a INVALID ARGUMENT SUPPLIED FOR FOREACH. I could set the ARRAY finding FIRST, but if there's more than 1 row it will only display the first.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

The function in the Field Controller:

```
public function add($id){

    //Set Title, Stylesheet, homelogo & layout  
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'View Invoices');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');   
    $this->layout='home_layout';

    //Find all fields where template_id = template_id passed in
    //ARRAY: to print foreach loop ONLY WORK >2 Row returned
    $templatefields=$this->Field->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
    'Field.template_id' => $id)));

    //Find all fields where template_id = template_id passed in
    //FIRST: to print echo variable ONLY WORK =1 Row returned
    //$templatefields=$this->Field->find('first', array(
    //'conditions' => array(
    //'Field.template_id' => $id)));

    //Set variables
    $this->set('templatefields', $templatefields); 
}
```

$id that is passed in is the Template id that the fields belong to.

The display function in Fields/add.ctp.

```
<?php
if (is_array($templatefields))
{
    foreach ($templatefields as $templatefield)
    {
        <tr>
            <td align='center'><?php echo $templatefields['Field']['name']; ?></td>
            <td align='center'><?php echo $templatefields['Field']['description']; ?></td>
            <td align='center'><?php echo $templatefields['Field']['default_value']; ?></td>
            <td align='center'><?php echo $templatefields['Field']['template_id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    }
}
else if (count($templatefields)==1)
{
    ....print? --> WOULD HAVE TO USE $templatefields where find('first') 
    ....otherwise error=invalid argument supplied for foreach
}
else if (empty($templatefields))
{
    ....NULL
    ....OR "There are no fields to display"
}
?>
```

Comment: what is problem with find('all'....) statement

Comment: I don't get it. Do a `find('all')`, if there are no results, display a *"Sorry, nothing here"* message, else loop through all found results (which may only be one) and output them. I don't understand why *one result* is a special case here.

Comment: If you do find(all) it expects an array, so when you for each loop & there's only 1 row, it's not an array & it throws an "invalid argument supplied for for each",.. Because it technically can't find an "array".

Comment: within your `foreach` you are still referring to `$templatefieldS` - shouldn't that be `$templatefield`?. `find('all')` returns an array regardless of the number of records found. (false if none)

Answer (score 3):

`find('all')` returns either `false` or an Array.

Therefore, `$templatefields` will either be `false`, or an Array - always.  Even if it's just one result, it's still in the same format and is still an Array.

Your code (modified):

```
<?php
if(empty($templatefields)) {

    //display "none found" message

} else {

    foreach ($templatefields as $templatefield) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'><?php echo $templatefields['Field']['name']; ?></td>
            <td align='center'><?php echo $templatefields['Field']['description']; ?></td>
            <td align='center'><?php echo $templatefields['Field']['default_value']; ?></td>
            <td align='center'><?php echo $templatefields['Field']['template_id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. The foreach loop wasn't working with 1 record yesterday, but if it should definitely work as above, I might just double check the code- could be something else throwing the error. Thanks.